# Allee effect plot with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I'm trying to use Tikz to plot a rough schematic of the "Allee effect" in population dynamics. However, I've been struggling with the finishing touches.

Below is my try:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[->] (-3,0) -- (4.2,0) node[right] {$x$};
  \draw[->] (0,-3) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {$f(x)$};
  \draw[scale=0.5,domain=-1:6.5,smooth,variable=\x,blue] plot ({\x},{0.5*\x*(\x-6)*(1-\x/1.8)});
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And this is what I'm looking to get:

[image]

Drawing the "flow" arrows on the plot it's been a headache. Can someone please point me in the right direction? It'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add the arrow tips with the help of the `decorations.markings` library, the intersections with the axis can be found and marked with help of the `intersections` library, and the nodes can be placed for example relative to the intersections using the `positioning` library.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,intersections,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={
markings,% switch on markings
mark=at position 0.2 with {\arrow{stealth}},
mark=at position 0.25 with {\arrowreversed{stealth}},
mark=at position 0.32 with {\arrowreversed{stealth}},
mark=at position 0.4 with {\arrow{stealth}},
mark=at position .8 with {\arrow{stealth}},
mark=at position .9 with {\arrowreversed{stealth}}}]

  \draw[->,name path=xaxis] (-3,0) -- (4.2,0) node[right] {$x$};
  \draw[->] (0,-3) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {$f(x)$};
  \draw[scale=0.5,domain=-1:6.5,smooth,variable=\x,blue,postaction={decorate},name path=plotline] plot ({\x},{0.5*\x*(\x-6)*(1-\x/1.8)});

\fill [name intersections={of=xaxis and plotline}] (intersection-1) circle[radius=2pt] (intersection-2) circle[radius=2pt] (intersection-3) circle[radius=2pt];

\node [below left=of intersection-1] {$n=a$};
\node [below right=of intersection-1] {$n=b$};
\node [below right=of intersection-3] {$n=k$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```